# joint result for multiple condition on same column

Tags: mysql

I want to select two column of data depending on a single column with multiple where condition.

```
SELECT country.countryname,COUNT(users.uid) as cnt
FROM users
JOIN country
ON users.country = country.countrycode
WHERE users.useractivated = 1 AND users.status = 'on'
GROUP BY users.country
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 30
```

this query gives me the main cnt column. Now I want an additional cnt2 column

which selects with following condition

```
users.status <> 'on'
```

but for only those 30 previously primarily selected countries.

So the output will look like

```
+----------------+-------+---------+
|   countryname  |   cnt | cnt2    |
+----------------+-------+---------+
| USA            | 1012  |  12     |
| CANADA         | 1125  |  135    |
| ...            | ...   |  ...    |
+----------------+-------+---------+
```

How can I acheieve that?

Comment: without input table datas how come we understand output table content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUM with if

```
SUM(IF(users.status = 'on', 1, 0)) AS cnt
```

or

```
SUM(IF(users.status <> 'on', 1, 0)) AS cnt2
```

Query :-

```
SELECT country.countryname,
SUM(IF(users.status = 'on', 1, 0)) AS cnt,
SUM(IF(users.status <> 'on', 1, 0)) AS cnt2
FROM users
JOIN country
ON users.country = country.countrycode
WHERE users.useractivated = 1
GROUP BY users.country
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 30
```